# C++ Interface (Header) and Implementation File Won't Work

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I am taking a C++ class, and for some reason I can't get the classes in my header file to work on one of my programs. I am using Visual Studio 2017, and I added both my header file and my implementation file together with my test file by using the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.

I have two constructors in my program, one default and one not. I tried deleting the second one from each file, and the program ran, but I can't get it to work otherwise.

**Header File:**

```
#pragma once
class BuckysClass {
public:
BuckysClass();
BuckysClass(string);
void coolSaying();
};
```

**Implementation File:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "BuckysClass.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

BuckysClass::BuckysClass() {
   cout << "Bucky is ";
}
BuckysClass::BuckysClass(string x) {
   cout << x;
}
void BuckysClass::coolSaying() {
   cout << "preachin to the choir" << endl;
}
```

**Test File:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BuckysClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

BuckysClass buckysObject;
buckysObject.coolSaying();

BuckysClass buckysObject2("Bucky is not ");
buckysObject2.coolSaying();
system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you include the actual code and not link to pictures?

Comment: Yeah on it hold on.

Comment: You showed the code for the class itself, but not the code that is trying to use the class. What is the ACTUAL PROBLEM you are having with it? You say it doesn't work, but HOW does it not work?

Comment: Yeah sorry I don't have 10 reputation points yet because I just made my account, so I could only add 2 pictures. I added the test file and the error messages I got below in an answer to myself XD . Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header file BuckysClass.h does not have the `<string>` Header file included.

Add:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
```

you should remove these includes from the corresponding .cpp file and just keep BuckysClass.h in cpp files.

Comment: Pfft I feel kinda dumb now :). Thanks Shashank!

Comment: Can we not advise beginners to write `using namespace std` in headers please?

Comment: @useless i think the answer says the same .

Answer (score 1):

syntax error：identifier 'string'

```
#include <string>//include the string header
class BuckysClass {
public:
  BuckysClass();
  BuckysClass(std::string);//add the namespace identifier
  void coolSaying();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some more pictures of the test file and the error message I got that I couldn't post above.

[Test File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjupP.png)

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF2l4.png)

Comment: Line 28 calls the constructor with string parameter. Without this, C++ tries to match this to the default copy constructor.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. What do you think I should do then?

Comment: ?!? You are the programmer. Say me what YOU want to do!

Comment: Harrison, important notes about Stack Overflow. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. There is one question. Everything pertaining to the question goes into the question. The rest is comments and answers. Comments should be used to ask for clarifications or raise points unrelated to the question but may he helpful. Answers should only be used to answer the question. This doesn't answer the question.